# Control RG6 Gripper mounted on UR5 robot arm

Tags: ur5, gripper, universal-robots

I want to control the OnRobot RG6 gripper mounted to a UR5 robot arm via ROS noetic. But I am having a problem connecting my PC to the robot with RG6 through Ethernet.

UR5 without RG6 was running fine based on [universal_robot's instruction](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver). Then, I tried to control RG6 based on [these instructions](https://github.com/Osaka-University-Harada-Laboratory/onrobot) and used the Ethernet Connection & External Control script(URCap) like the UR5 case.

I assumed the gripper and the arm share the same IP, so I used the robot IP, which ran into an error. I kept trying by changing the robot IP to the same IP as the default IP of RG6 Gripper, which is 192.168.1.1 and default port: 502, but nothing happened, and eventually, I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ExceptionResponse' object has no attribute 'registers'
[DEBUG] [1696923112.318935]: [/OnRobotRGInput] failed to receive incoming message : unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
[OnRobotRGTcpNode-2] process has died [pid 14410, exit code 1, cmd /home/mngu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/onrobot_rg_control/OnRobotRGTcpNode.py __name:=OnRobotRGTcpNode __log:=/home/mngu/.ros/log/a4614100-673e-11ee-9256-03bb5f0dd7a5/OnRobotRGTcpNode-2.log].
log file: /home/mngu/.ros/log/a4614100-673e-11ee-9256-03bb5f0dd7a5/OnRobotRGTcpNode-2*.log
[OnRobotRGTcpNode-2] restarting process
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, Did you find any solution? If yes, can you share it here.